# Gaussian filter in Python

Tags: python, smoothing, contourf

I have a 3d array and I took a central slice of it (the slice [:,:,64]) and I made a contour plot (x,y) with these data. It gives me a density field. Now, I need to smooth this density field by applying a Gaussian filter. I am new to Python and I don't know, what should I do?
a)Smooth my data and make a contour plot again with the smoothed data?
b)Smooth the contour plot I already have?
And in any case, which is the code doing it?
If anybody could help with that I would appreciate that.
I also attach my density field (represented by a contour plot).[image: Density Field]

Comment: not to be condescending but have you tried google? Literally the first result is scipy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html

Comment: I think option A is the one I would pick. I would use the function BlueScr33n links to.

Comment: Yes, I tried google and I applied the commands you refer to, but I could not take the result I want. Thanks a lot for your comments, both of you!!